# Spring RequestMapping with timestamp in URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to have a dynamic URL in Spring for downloading CSVs, e.g.
`Bernhard_content_24Feb2017.csv`. More formally this would be

`{id}_content_{timestamp}.csv`

Every request like `Me_content_1Jan2017.csv` or `You_content_31Dec2017.csv` should go to the method in the code below (getCsv(...)). Note, that I want to **keep the suffix .csv** . The user should download a file with a name like  `Me_content_1Jan2017.csv`.

So I tried this in Spring:

```
@RequestMapping("{id}_content_{timestamp}.csv")
public void getCsv(@PathVariable String id, @PathVariable String timestamp, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.getWriter().print(createCsv(id));
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

What would be the correct syntax for this? Given, that it's possible.

Thanks,

Bernhard

**UPDATE:**

I went for this solution (renaming the URL a little bit, now like `Me_1Jan2017_content.csv`):

```
@RequestMapping("{idAndTimestamp}_content.csv")
public void getCsv(@PathVariable String idAndTimestamp, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String id = idAndTimestamp.split("_")[0];
    response.getWriter().print(createCsv(id));
}
```

Comment: why don't u get currentTime.millis() as the path rather then something like Bernhard_content_24Feb2017 and generate the csv file and you can give any name ..... then after strem it for the client...

Comment: Could you please mention timestamp and ID format?

Comment: ID and timestamp are just random strings. So ID is [a-zA-Z0-9].* and timestamp, too. BTW, I don't use the timestamp. I just want, that the user downloads a file with the timestamp in it: `<a href="Bernhard_content_24Feb2017.csv">Download CSV</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a way to use complex definition for @PathVariable. Try getting the full file name in one variable and splitting the parts in your method. Something like this.

```
@RequestMapping("{fileName}")
    public void getCsv(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable String  fileName) {
    String[] parts = fileName.split(".")[0].split("_");
    String id = parts[0];
    String timestamp = parts[2];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was going for your solution, splitting 1 PathVariable instead of using 2 PathVariables.

Answer (score 1):

Change your id and timestamp parameters like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "downloadCvs/{id}/{timestamp}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void getCsv(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable String id, @PathVariable String timestamp) {

    response.setContentType("text/csv"); 

    String reportName = "CSV_Report_Name_What_you_Want.csv"; 

    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename="+reportName); 

    response.getOutputStream().print(createCsv(id)); 

    response.getOutputStream().flush();
}
```

Comment: I think, that's pretty close to a solution ;-)
But: the user should download a file with a name like "Bernhard_content_24Feb2017.csv", in your case the file name would be just "24Feb2017" (without .csv, I guess).

Comment: Absolutely yes but what about setting file name at controller like this: response.setContentType("text/csv");
String reportName = "CSV_Report_Name_What_you_Want.csv";
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename="+reportName); response.getOutputStream().print(createCsv(id));
response.getOutputStream().flush();Just write content to HttpServletResponse. Is this a more practical solution for you?

Comment: Yes, that would have been better, so +1.
In the end, I went with a slightly different solution.
Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

you should try something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{path}/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getCsv(@PathVariable("path") String path, HttpServletRequest request){
    //your code here...
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
@RequestMapping("{filename:.+}") //putting ".+" will keep ".csv" extension otherwise you will lose it.
public void getCsv(@PathVariable(fileName) String  fileName) {
    String[] parts = fileName.split("_");
    String id = parts[0];
    String timestamp = parts[2].split(".")[0];
}
```

If you want to make it more confined use:

```
@RequestMapping("{filename:[A-Za-z0-9]+(_content_)[A-Za-z0-9]+(.csv)}")
```

Hope it helps.